# How do I alter keyframes for a new framerate?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I created a new scene for a new animation. I didn't know this at the time, but a new scene is a new world, so settings will be back to default. I made *all* my weapons, models, HUD elements, and others with the *default* settings. Whats the problem with this? I have 60 fps for my animation framerate, but the new scene has it on 24.

Yes, I should simply increase it to 60 to match everything else, but **all my animations will run faster than 2x regular/intended speed**. I could set it to 60, and do whats on my mind: delete and rework *all* of the tons of animations I have created.  I obviously am looking to an alternative, and I am thinking that, hopefully, in some way, I can take an animation and maybe move the frames or have all the frames moved by a percentage (example: original frames = 10, moved by 150% makes total 15 frames)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In object mode, select all the objects for which the animation rate needs to be changed from 24 to 60 fps.

In the graph editor, place the 2D cursor at frame zero, and set the pivot center to *2D Cursor*

Hit <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice to select all of your keyframes. (You may want to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide the curve handles if it looks too busy)

Hit <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>X</kbd> to scale horizontally, then type 2.5, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This scales your 24 frames-per-second animations out a multiple of 2.5 to 60 frames-per-second.

Comment: I'm so glad this is in the engine, I sort of felt hopeless as I didn't know this existed. I'll take a better look and test it when I can. Thanks though! :)