# Scale F-curve from time/ 3D cursor

Tags: 3d-cursor, fcurves

A while ago I saw a demo where the f-curve could be scaled from a specific point in the time line - if I remember correctly determined by the 3D cursor - but I have not been able to recreate it. What I want to do is scale the points along the X-axis from a certain start frame. The default behavior seems to be the scaling is always from the middle which is not helpful in my case. Any ideas what I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Change pivot.. Used here - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40334/how-do-i-alter-keyframes-for-a-new-framerate

Comment: @Patdog Please don't add "Solved" in the title. Wait for someone to post an answer or write an answer yourself. If your question was a duplicate, mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I overlooked the 'hidden' menu, obscured by my small window. With thanks to Mr Zak for pointing out the 'change pivot', and my discovery of the 2D cursor.